# can i get build in node js back-end code ? if yes means, how to get node js build using npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a node js api service application. I don't want to share my code with client. so, i decide to make a build like react, ionic in node js. but, i don't have any idea. please help me to get build in node js or any other way to prevent my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node.JS has many inbuilt frontends and packages - Express, Pug/Jade, Vue...many options.

Comment: @JackBashford I used express. now my question is how to make a build or bundle my node js project?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it. Javascript is not a compiled language, so even if you minify and uglify it, your client will always be able to decode it a bit.

Comment: @Maelig that is not a problem. now I need to prevent my code. if you know any way, please share here.

Comment: @Maelig  there is any way to make a build ?

Comment: prevent your code ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Instead of selling the software and giving him the code, host the code and make him pay for it... lookup *SaSS* (Software as a Service)

Comment: @Maelig I mean, I don't want to share my code to client. so, i need to make a build of my application like react,ionic builds

Comment: I posted an answer

Comment: you can bundle it as an executable to give to your client

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not a compiled code, the best you can do is minify and uglify it (obfuscate).

You can bundle your NodeJS project as you want, anyone accessing the obfuscated code will always be able to retro-engineering it.

There are multiple ways to do it, here is one (not tested myself) : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/607/how-to-obfuscate-javascript-code-with-node-js

You can bundle a NodeJS as an executable : https://dev.to/jochemstoel/bundle-your-node-app-to-a-single-executable-for-windows-linux-and-osx-2c89

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are multiple ways but as per my opinion two way is good first create a build using `TypeScript` and second way convert your nodejs code into Byte using `Bytenode`

> `TypeScript` has had first class support for Node.js, you can type
>   your code in TypeScript and compile it using `tsc app.ts` Its create
>   `app.js`.
>
> `Bytenode` tool truly compiles your JavaScript code into `V8 bytecode`.

You can take reference from [Bytenode doc on npm](https://github.com/OsamaAbbas/bytenode) and [Typescript + Node + Express](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/typescript-with-node-and-express-js-why-when-and-how-eb6bc73edd5d), I think its help you.

Comment: it'll still be a readable version, he wants to prevent code reading from his client

Comment: @Jelly Fish do you have any example or reference link ?

Comment: @HariharanAR I updated my answer, maybe its help, need more help, please ask me. Thanks